# Log em Arquivos Distintos [Log4Net]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, log

Utilizo na minha aplicação o Log4Net. Preciso criar uma configuração que "deposite" tudo o que for do level="INFO" em um arquivo e tudo o que for leve="ERRO" em outro arquivo.

Mas mesmo seguindo os tutoriais, não funcionam. Vejam como fiz abaixo. Desde já agradeço...

```
<log4net>
  <root name="LogFilesAll">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileErro"/>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileInfo"/>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
  </root>

  <!-- APPENDER DE ERRO -->
  <appender name="RollingFileErro" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="GestorReq32Error.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>    
  </appender>

  <!-- APPENDER DE ERRO -->
  <appender name="RollingFileInfo" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="GestorReq32Info.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  </appender>

  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

</log4net>
```

Comment: O arquivo `log4net.config` está junto o `.exe` da sua aplicação?

Comment: Sim, está no mesmo diretório e consigo gerar o log, mas apenas um arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina o `loglevel` dentro `appender` pelo `filter`. 
Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados [aqui](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#Filters)

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
       <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
       <levelMax value="DEBUG" />      
</filter>
```

Por exemplo:

```
<log4net>
  <root name="LogFilesAll">
    <!-- Aqui deixe "ALL" para processar todos os tipos de logs -->
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileErro"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileInfo"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
  </root>

  <!-- APPENDER DE ERRO -->
  <appender name="RollingFileErro" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="GestorReq32Error.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
    <!-- Define o filtro -->
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter"> 
           <levelMin value="ERROR"/>
           <levelMax value="ERROR" />      
    </filter>    
  </appender>

  <!-- APPENDER DE INFO -->
  <appender name="RollingFileInfo" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="GestorReq32Info.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %date{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
    <!-- Define o filtro -->
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
           <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
           <levelMax value="INFO" />
    </filter>          
  </appender>

  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

</log4net>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado.